# Visual Studio C++ CMake Error: Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: gl)

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, build, clone, wxwidgets

I've been struggling to build the source of a particular package located here: https://bitbucket.org/wowmodelviewer/wowmodelviewer/src/master/

All of the libraries are located in the "sdk" here: https://bitbucket.org/wowmodelviewer/wmv_sdk/src/master/

I've configured the environment variables in the CMakeSettings.json file:
[image]

However when the project builds, it fails with:

FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
**Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: gl)**

[image]

It looks like WXWidgets is found but the "GL" is missing? How can I fix this and build this source code?

Comment: Well, it seems that the project you want to build needs some GL-related library among libraries provided by wxWidgets. It could be a library with name such as `libwxgl.lib` or so. Make sure that directory you specifying in `wxWidgets_LIB_DIR` variable containts such library.

Comment: Also, please replace **images** with the **text** they contain. Incomplete images have a little value. With over 500 reputation you should be aware that Stack Overflow discourages images...

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev!